# AngularJS Memory consumption on service call

Tags: angularjs, loops, memory, while-loop

I'm trying to get all results from a service that is providing me objects to work with on the frontpage. Thing is, the service only provides 50 objects at a time, but i needed to get all of them at once (I'm testing with a value around ~1500), by pushing objects into my objects array.

So far my code is messy and kinda not 'dry'. I tried to do something like this:

```
$scope.getObjects = function() {

        Objects.get(nextGroup).then(function(data) {
            $scope.MyObjects = data.objects;
            while(nextGroup != null) {
                Objects.get(nextGroup).then(function(data) {
                    angular.forEach(data.objects, function(object) {
                        $scope.MyObjects.push(object);
                    });
                    nextGroup = data.nextGroup;
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

Naturally, Chrome breaks after a while.

What can I do?

Comment: .then is not synchronous, your while loop might run like millions and .then will executed millions too.

Comment: Is there a known total in response from first request? As YOU pointed out you are creating an infinite loop with your `while`